, Spring4 - oauth doesn't use refresh-token. Grant-type passwords (In spring 6 everything works)
I'm encountering an issue with OAuth in Spring 4, using Spring Boot 1.5.9.
My setup includes using the grant type "password" and involves the following components: OAuth2RestTemplate, ResourceOwnerPasswordResourceDetails, and AccessTokenProvider.
Here's the problem: My access token expires after 30 minutes. Within these 30 minutes, my application uses the initial access token for all requests, which is expected. However, after the 30-minute mark, when I make a new request, the system erroneously uses the "password" grant type again instead of switching to "refresh_token" grant type. I should be using the refresh token that I received along with the access token initially.
Interestingly, when I tested this in the newer versions of Spring (6) and Spring Boot (3.2), the application correctly switches to using the "refresh_token" grant type after 30 minutes.
Unfortunately, these classes are not available in Spring 4, and I'm stuck trying to find a workaround.
Here is the code snippet from my Spring 4 setup:
@Configuration
@EnableOAuth2Client
public class OAuthClientConfig {

@Value("${oauth.client-id}")
private String clientId;

@Value("${oauth.client-secret}")
private String clientSecret;

@Value("${oauth.scope}")
private String scope;

@Value("${oauth.token-uri}")
private String tokenUri;

@Value("${oauth.username}")
private String username;

@Value("${oauth.password}")
private String password;

@Bean
public OAuth2RestTemplate oauth2RestTemplate() {
    ResourceOwnerPasswordResourceDetails resourceDetails = new ResourceOwnerPasswordResourceDetails();
    resourceDetails.setClientId(clientId);
    resourceDetails.setClientSecret(clientSecret);
    resourceDetails.setAccessTokenUri(tokenUri);
    resourceDetails.setScope(Arrays.asList(scope.split(",")));
    resourceDetails.setUsername(username);
    resourceDetails.setPassword(password);

    DefaultOAuth2ClientContext clientContext = new DefaultOAuth2ClientContext();
    return new OAuth2RestTemplate(resourceDetails, clientContext);
}

@Bean
public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
    return new RestTemplate();
}

}
@RestController
@Slf4j
public class ApiController {

@Autowired
private OAuth2RestTemplate oauth2RestTemplate;

@Value("${api.prices.url}")
private String pricesApiUrl;

@GetMapping("/cars")
public ResponseEntity<String> getPrices() {
    try {
        String urlWithParams = buildUrl();
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<>(headers);
        return oauth2RestTemplate.exchange(urlWithParams, HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("Error processing the request: ", e);
        return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body("Error processing the request: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

